# string encryption in javascript and decryption in java

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

My requirement is, we need to encrypt the password string in java script and that should be decrypted in Java. For this requirement i am using the below code. but i got the error like

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
>       at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)

my code snippet is

java script Code:

```
   var encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, key, {

    });
```

Java Code is...

```
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(encryptedData.getBytes());
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
```

Here the key is generated in Java.

can anyone help me out, to resolve this issue.

or If you have any working example please provide me that once

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

From my observation, the mode and padding are not same.
I have not test this but please try this,

on javascript

```
<script>
    var blockAndPadding = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC , padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding};
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", blockAndPadding);
</script>
```

on java side, change method parameter to the following.

`Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I have included the below js in my jsp

<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

if i pass call backs, its not encrypting the text. In the developer console its saying some of the variables are not define.
please provide a proper plugin for the encryption.